# How can I split a xml document into strings between a certain tag?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

Say I have the following XML:

```
<foo>
<spam taste="great"> stuff</spam> <spam taste="moldy"> stuff</spam>
<bar taste="eww"> stuff </bar> <bar> stuff </bar> 
<bacon taste="yum"> stuff </bacon><bacon taste="yum"> stuff </bacon><bacon taste="yum"> stuff </bacon>
</foo>
```

With spam, bar, and bacon being data tags with more tags inside, I want to split the XML into this

- `<spam taste="great"> stuff</spam> <spam taste="moldy"> stuff</spam>`,
- `<bar taste="eww"> stuff </bar> <bar> stuff </bar>`,
- `<bacon taste="yum"> stuff </bacon><bacon taste="yum"> stuff </bacon><bacon taste="yum"> stuff </bacon>`,

in order to reorder it for parsing.

The basic structure like this, with the blocks being in any order.

```
<foo>
block of bar tags
block of spam tags
block of bacon tags
</foo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [ElementTree methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

document = ET.parse("file.xml")
spams = document.findall("spam")
bars = document.findall("bar")
bacon = 'document.findall("bacon")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what the names of the tags are at runtime + just want to break up the elements by group, you can perhaps try using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in combination with whatever xml parsing library you want:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import itertools

raw_xml = '''<foo>
<spam taste="great"> stuff</spam> <spam taste="moldy"> stuff</spam>
<bar taste="eww"> stuff </bar> <bar> stuff </bar> 
<bacon taste="yum"> stuff </bacon><bacon taste="yum"> stuff </bacon><bacon taste="yum"> stuff </bacon>
<spam taste="Great">stuff2</spam>
</foo>'''

groups = itertools.groupby(et.fromstring(raw_xml), lambda element: element.tag)
groups = [list(group[1]) for group in groups]

print groups
```

The output would then be:

```
[[<Element 'spam' at 0x218ecb0>, <Element 'spam' at 0x218ee10>], 
 [<Element 'bar' at 0x218ee90>, <Element 'bar' at 0x218eeb0>], 
 [<Element 'bacon' at 0x218ef30>, <Element 'bacon' at 0x218ef50>, <Element 'bacon' at 0x218ef90>], 
 [<Element 'spam' at 0x218efd0>]]
```

If you need the actual string value, you can do:

```
print [[et.tostring(element) for element in group] for group in groups]
```

...which will get you:

```
[['<spam taste="great"> stuff</spam> ', '<spam taste="moldy">stuff</spam>\n'],
 ['<bar taste="eww"> stuff </bar> ', '<bar> stuff </bar> \n'], 
 ['<bacon taste="yum"> stuff </bacon>', '<bacon taste="yum"> stuff </bacon>', '<bacon taste="yum">stuff </bacon>\n'], 
 ['<spam taste="Great">stuff2</spam>\n']]
```

Comment: I do know the names at runtime, and I want to group together all the tags of each type.

Comment: Does this work even if there are many, many nested tags inside of each spam, bacon, and bar tags?

Comment: @JamesLu -- if you know the names at runtime and don't care about keeping each group separate (ie you just want _all_ spam elements, _all_ bar elements, and so forth), then Daniel's solution below will probably work better for you. If you want to preserve each block (so spam bar spam spam will result in 3 groups), then my solution would work better. Nesting: my solution will ignore any nesting inside the tags + keep them the same. Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: True. I'm parsing OSM XML in my case so Daniel's solution here is better.